# Using (array() in custom conditional functions

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

How can I create an array of multiple `endpoint` for the below custom conditional code?

```
function is_single_with_endpoint( $endpoint ) {
global $wp_query;
   if ( ! isset( $endpoint ) && ! empty( $endpoint ) ) {
       return false;
   }
   if ( array_key_exists( $endpoint, $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

This will work is I use

```
if ( ! is_single_with_endpoint('overview') && ! is_single_with_endpoint('analytics') ) {
```

but not as

```
if ( ! is_single_with_endpoint(array('overview','analytics')) ){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just step through the array of inputs and check each one for a failure. If none of them produce failure, then it passes at the end.

```
function is_single_with_endpoint($endpoints) {
    global $wp_query;

    // Iterate through set (can be set of one)
    foreach ((array)$endpoints AS $endpoint) {
        if (empty($endpoint)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!array_key_exists($endpoint, $wp_query->query_vars)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Didn't fail, so it passes
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it still doesn't seem to apply as `if ( ! is_single_with_endpoint(array('overview','analytics')) ){` Any suggestions?

Comment: Please elaborate. What's not happening?

Comment: If I add a function with the condition of `if ( ! is_single_with_endpoint('overview') && ! is_single_with_endpoint('analytics') ) { //function }` this will work as intended. Yet, if I add the condition in an array as `if ( ! is_single_with_endpoint(array('overview','analytics')) ){ //function }`, even with your suggestion the function will not work as intended.

Comment: Please do a `var_dump()` of `$wp_query->query_vars` and make sure it contains what you expect. When I test with this:
`$wp_query=(object)['query_vars'=>1];` 
`$wp_query->query_vars = ['overview'=>1,'analytics'=>2];` 
It returns TRUE, as expected, and FALSE if I put anything else in it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this, instead:

```
function is_single_with_endpoint($endpoint = null){
  global $wp_query;
  if($endpoint === null){
    return false;
  }
  if(is_array($endpoint)){
    foreach($endpoint as $k => $v){
      if(!array_key_exists($k, $wp_query->query_vars)){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    if(!array_key_exists($endpoint)){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it still doesn't seem to apply as if ( ! is_single_with_endpoint(array('overview','analytics')) ){ Any suggestions? –